# How to delete the individual item from the localStorage dynamically

Tags: jquery, listview, checkbox, local-storage

I'm trying to delete the individual items from the localStorage using jquery. Here i'm adding the checkboxes to each and every item in the listivew for removing the seleted checkbox's items have to delete from localStorage but its not working correctly.

**Updated Code**:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#section_list").on('click', 'a', function() {
                var item = $(this).find('h2').text();
                var desc = $(this).find('p').text();
                var html = '<p></br><p class="description">' + desc + '</p>';
                $('.addToFavoritesDiv').click(function() {
                    var url = $(location).attr('href');
                    if (!supportLocalStorage())
                    {
                        item = 'No support';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        try
                            {
                                localStorage.setItem('autosave' + url, item + html);

                            }
                        catch (e)
                            {
                                if (e == QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR)
                                {
                                    alert('Quota Exceeded');
                                }
                            }   
                    }
                });
    });

    $('#fav').click(function() {
        fromStorage();
        $("#favoritesList").listview('refresh');
    }); 

    $(document).on('click', '#edit', function() {
        fromGetStorage();
    });
});

function supportLocalStorage()
{       
    return typeof(Storage) !== 'undefined';
}

function fromStorage()
{
    $("#favoritesList").empty();
    $("#favoritesList").listview('refresh');
    for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
        var url = localStorage.key(i);
            var item = localStorage.getItem(url);
            $("#favoritesList").append('<li id="add"><a href="' + url + '" style="text-decoration:none;color:black">' + item  + '</a></li>').attr('url', url);
    }
    $("#favoritesList").listview('refresh');
}

function fromGetStorage() 
    {   
     $("#favoritesList").empty();  
     $("#favoritesList").append('<input type="checkbox" name="all" id="select" />Select all</br>');
     $("#fav .ui-listview-filter").remove();
        for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
        var url = localStorage.key(i);
         var item = localStorage.getItem(url);
          $("#favoritesList").append('<li id="add"><div><input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check">&nbsp;<a href="' + url + '" style="text-decoration:none;color:black">' + item + '</a></div></li>').attr('url', url);
        $("#favoritesList").listview('refresh');
 }

$("#select").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
    $('#select').change(function() {
    if($("#select").is(':checked')) {
        $("#add #check").prop("checked", true);
        $('#empty').on('click', function() {
            localStorage.clear();
        $("#favoritesList").listview('refresh');
        });
    }
    else {
        $("#add #check").prop("checked", false);
    }
 });


$("#add #check").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});

    $("#add #check").change(function() {
        var chkLength = $('input[name="check"]:checkbox').length;
        var chkdLength = $('input[name="check"]:checkbox:checked').length;
        if (chkLength == chkdLength)
        {
            $('#select').prop('checked', true);
            $('#empty').on('click', function() {
                localStorage.clear();
                $("#favoritesList").listview('refresh');
            });
        }
        else 
        {
            $('#select').prop('checked', false);
        }
        $("#delete").on('click', function() {
                var checked = $('#add #check:checkbox:checked');
                    var url = localStorage.key(checked);
                    localStorage.removeItem(url);
                    $("#favoritesList").listview('refresh');
            $("#favoritesList").listview('refresh');
        });

});

}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Were you able to find an answer to this? I'm having the same issue deleting specific records from a listview of favorites.

Answer (score 30):

Are you using boolean values as key? It won't work.

It should be :

```
localStorage.removeItem('keyName');
```

or

```
delete window.localStorage["keyName"]
```

Comment: i'm trying to delete the checked list items from the listview which is stored in localstorage

Comment: You storing object in localstorage? I thought we can just store string values. How about just storing Ids and deleting items by their ids.

Comment: yes i'm storing the favorite pages in the localstorage. I'm able to delete all the data in localstorage using "localStorage.clear()" but i'm unable to delete the individual items

Comment: can you post your method of saving data.

Answer (score 2):

If you're thinking about the numerical key, here's something that seems to work.

```
var elems = -1;
var deleteElem;
```

Then loop through the local storage to find whatever element you're looking for (in this case, the first one):

```
$.each( localStorage, function( key,value ){
    elems++;
    // define which element to delete
    if(elems == 0){ deleteElem = key }
});
```

Now that you've got the key you need, just remove it with:

```
localStorage.removeItem(deleteElem);
```